# What LEGO set do these bags belong to?

Tags: set-identification

Any idea what set this might be? Number on bags say 529R9. I have unopened bags 2-6 and one loose bag of LEGO bricks.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is [41340: Friendship House](https://brickset.com/sets/41340-1/Friendship-House)
[image]

keyparts :

- [93092: Minifigure, Utensil Basket in Medium Lavender](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93092&idColor=157#T=C&C=157)
- [41539: Plate 8 x 8 in Lime](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41539&idColor=34#T=C&C=34)
- [2584: String Reel 2 x 2 Holder in Black](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2584&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

Comment: I keep being shocked at the ease with which people on this site can recognize things like this. I could probably post a mixed pile of bricks from 2 sets and you would be able to tell me which 2 sets I mixed.

Comment: @Nzall it's usually done by identifying a few relatively uncommon elements across the bags, and knowing what colours typically appear in which themes ;)